# Why do links over image work in Chrome/Firefox but not in Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, hyperlink

I created an image with some links on top of it [here](http://www.pythonforspss.org/managing-variable-properties-1-introduction/#overview). It works as it should in Google Chrome and Firefox but not in Internet Explorer 8. Does anybody know how/whether I could fix that?

Comment: I assume your are referring to the borders that appear on hovering over the image.  This does not seem to work in IE10.

Comment: Yes, I noticed. I there any way to MAKE it work, though?

Comment: It looks like IE doesn't count it as hover if you hover over a transparent part.

Comment: Could you reproduce some of the relevant markup here or describe it more specifically? This is in case the site in question becomes unavailable in the future.

Answer (score 1):

For some obscure reason, IE sometimes "doesn't like" completely transparent areas of absolutely positioned links. Setting any explicit background to them other than default `transparent none` (`background: url(about:blank)` "hack" usually does the trick) seems to make IE treat them correctly. In IE9+, `background:rgba(0,0,0,0)` also seems to do the trick (although it should be just the same as `transparent` [per CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparent)).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to specify the z-index of the image to ensure it appears behind the links in IE8.

Comment: That didn't help. With `z-index:-1;` on the image, it becomes invisible. When I set it to `0`, nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

i dont have your code but i think this may help you. try this class:

```
.dict {
position: relative;
margin-top: -138px;
float: left;
display: block;
height: 116px;
```

Answer (score 0):

On the links there should be a `z-index` value for start, in IE(6-7-8), `z-index` is only working when the parent element also has a `z-index` value:

```
.dict {
    display: block;
    height: 116px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 79px;
    z-index: 2;
}
<div style="position:relative;width:860px;height:200px;z-index:1;">
```

Comment: They already had `z-index:2;`. Setting it to `3` doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why it's not working. But the problem is solved (even for ie8) by removing the img from the html and using it as a background with CSS.